# group by date and getting a count of specific field

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have table of below format

```
'--------------------------------------
   ID|col1   |date_ts
--------------------------------------
1    |type1  | 2011-10-01 23:59:59.163-08
2    |type1  | 2011-10-02 21:42:20.152-19
3    |type2  | 2011-10-03 23:21:49.175-21
4    |type3  | 2011-10-03 23:19:39.169-12
5    |type2  | 2011-10-05 23:34:30.129-01'
```

I am trying to group by date and get count of each type in col1

Below is the output i am trying to achieve

```
' date        | type1  | type2     |type3 |
 ------------------------------------------
 2011-10-01   |    1   |  0        |  0   |
 2011-10-02   |    1   |  0        |  0   |
 2011-10-03   |    0   |  1        |  1   |
 2011-10-05   |    0   |  1        |  0   |'
```

I have the below query now. But getting run time errors.

```
'set hive.cli.print.header=true;
 select
 sum(if(col1 = 'type1', 1, 0)) as type_1,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type2', 1, 0)) as type_2,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type3', 1, 0)) as type_3
 from table1 WHERE unix_timestamp(date_ts) >= unix_timestamp('2011-10-01 00:00:00.178-01') AND       unix_timestamp (date_ts) <= unix_timestamp('2011-10-05 23:59:59.168-08')
 GROUP BY col1, TO_DATE(date_ts)
 ORDER BY date_ts;'
```

Any ideas on how to do this?Thanks

Comment: what language will you be applying this to?

Comment: i am trying to do it in hive

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 8:9 Invalid table alias or column reference 'date_ts': (possible column names are: type_1, type_2, type_3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose date_ts in the projected columns.

select **to_date(date_ts) date_ts,**
 sum(if(col1 = 'type1', 1, 0)) as type_1,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type2', 1, 0)) as type_2,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type3', 1, 0)) as type_3
 from table1 WHERE unix_timestamp(date_ts) >= unix_timestamp('2011-10-01 00:00:00.178-01') AND       unix_timestamp (date_ts) <= unix_timestamp('2011-10-05 23:59:59.168-08')
 GROUP BY col1, TO_DATE(date_ts)
 ORDER BY date_ts;'

Comment: Sorry, its not working. I think the query you mentioned may be right but there are some abnormalities with my data in the date_ts column. So used the datatype string instead of time stamp and used a substring to get the required output.

Comment: Well i pointed the way: your own solution does incorporate the aspect of including the date_ts column within the selected columns.  It's your choice on whether to award to me but in reverse situations I only award to myself when no other answer were more than marginally helpful.

Comment: thx!  I have upvoted your solution as well, to give credit for your work.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the where condition to filter out the dates. I used a substring to just get the date part of the entire column. And just did a GROUP BY on only date column

```
'select substr(ltrim(date_ts),0,10) date_ts,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type1', 1, 0)) as type_1,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type2', 1, 0)) as type_2,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type3', 1, 0)) as type_3
 from table1
 GROUP BY substr(ltrim(date_ts),0,10) 
 ORDER BY date_ts;'
```

My output

```
' date        | type1  | type2     |type3 |
 ------------------------------------------
 2011-10-01   |    1   |  0        |  0   |
 2011-10-02   |    1   |  0        |  0   |
 2011-10-03   |    0   |  1        |  1   |
 2011-10-05   |    0   |  1        |  0   |'
```